# How to combine sf elements (layers) in R

Tags: r, maps, gis, geospatial

despite having *some* experience with R, I am much less experienced using R for GIS-like tasks.
I have a shapefile of all communities within Germany and created a new object that only shows the borders of the 16 states of Germany.

```
gem <- readOGR(path/to/shapefile.shp) # reading shapefile
gemsf <- st_read(path/to/shapefile.shp) # reading shapefile as sf object


f00 <- gUnaryUnion(gem, id = gem@data$SN_L) # SN_L is the column of the various states - this line creates a new sp object with only the states instead of all communities

f002 <-  sf::st_as_sf(f00, coords = c("x","y")) # turning the object into an sf object, so graphing with ggplot is easier
```

To check my work so far I plotted the base data (communities) using

```
gemsf %>%
ggplot(data = .,) + geom_sf( aes(fill = SN_L)) # fill by state
```

as well as `plot(f002)` which creates a plot of the 16 states, while the ggplot-code provides a nice map of Germany by community, with each state filled in a different color.

Now I'd like to overlay this with a second layer that indicates the borders of the states (so if you e.g. plot population density you can still distinguish states easily).

My attempt to do so, I used "standard procedure" and added another layer

```
ggplot() + 
geom_sf(data = gemsf, aes(fill = SN_L)) +   # fill by state
geom_sf(data = f002) # since the f002 data frame/sf object ONLY has a geometry column, there is no aes()
```

results in the following output: https://i.ibb.co/qk9zWRY/ggplot-map-layer.png

So how do I get to add a second layer that only provides the borders and does not cover the actual layer of interest below? In QGIS or ArcGIS, this is common procedure and not a problem, and I'd like to be able to recreate this in R, too.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which I want to share with everyone.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = gemsf_data, aes(fill = log(je_km2))) +   # fill by state
  geom_sf(data = f002, alpha = 0, color = "black") + # since the f002 data frame/sf object ONLY has a geometry column, there is no aes()
  theme_minimal()
```

The trick was adding "alpha" not in the aes() part, but rather just as shown above.